# Can I keep downloaded Google Play musics even after I cancel my monthly subscription

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

After I cancel my Google Play Music monthly subscription, I wonder if I can keep/listen to previously downloaded music files from Google Play.

I take a look at [Google Play terms of service](https://play.google.com/intl/en-us_us/about/play-terms.html) section 5 and section 7, but it looks like spaghetti to me.

Comment: Can you clarify in what sense the material is "downloaded". There are legal and illegal ways to put stuff on your device. Purchasing content is probably distinct from having the right to access (e.g. Netflix-style access), and you can't legally "download" Netflix movies from your streaming account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access saved content for the simple reason that you are not allowed to save it in the first place:

> **Capturing of Streams**. You may not use Google Play or any Content in conjunction with any stream-ripping, stream capture or similar software to record or create a copy of any Content that is presented to you in streaming format.